# Match word in text file and highlight it

Tags: java, regex

I have an input like this in the text file
example :

> **Input file 1**: " opening of the shop on sunday"
>
> **Input file 2**: " Every friday , the discount will be "
>
> **Input file 3**: "start in the week on monday "

I want to build file for name of days, like this
file words:

- Saturday
- Sunday
- Monday
- Tuesday
- wednesday
- thursday
- friday

Can you help me code to match name of the day in text files
highlight name of day in text in java code

Comment: What did you try, show us some code and where you are facing problem?

Comment: Is input contain only one name of days?

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy task, I think. We need a list which contains name of days. Then read the file word by word and check if the list contains the word. If list contains the word, then its required and we will put it into the output file.
I am pasting my code here, please let me know if you want something else:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prgo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
        List<String> daysList = Arrays.asList(days);
        // We can create direct list also
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\vishal\\abc.txt"));
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\vishal\\days.txt"));

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String s = sc.next();
            if (daysList.contains(s)){
                wr.write(s);
            }

        }
        wr.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp expresion to parse the file name. I wrote two methods one return `List` of founded days name and other return only one value.

```
public class Test {

    private static final String file1 = "opening of the shop on sunday";
    private static final String file2 = "Every friday , the discount will be ";
    private static final String file3 = "start in the week on monday ";
    private static final String fileWithSeveralDays = "monday start in the week on monday and every thursday";

    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("(saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday)");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> fileToDaysMap = new HashMap<>();

        fileToDaysMap.put(file1, findAllMatches(file1));
        fileToDaysMap.put(file2, findAllMatches(file2));
        fileToDaysMap.put(file3, findAllMatches(file3));
        fileToDaysMap.put(fileWithSeveralDays, findAllMatches(fileWithSeveralDays));

        String singleDay = findSingleOrNull(file1);
    }

    private static Set<String> findAllMatches(String fileName) {
        Set<String> matches = new HashSet<>();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matches.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return matches;
    }

    private static String findSingleOrNull(String fileName) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
    }

}
```